# How to add a third party library in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using [simplexlsx.class.php](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx) library and I want to add in my codeigniter application.
I saved this file in application/third_party directory and load in application as

```
$this->load->library('simplexlsx.calss.php');
```

but codeigniter is giving me this error
*"Unable to load the requested class: Simplexlsx.class"*

How can I add this?

Comment: Typo? `simplexlsx.calss.php` (calss instead of class).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this is just a filename, which is already in github link.

Comment: Sure, but it will be hard to load a library if you enter an invalid filename. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Codeigniter library documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#naming-conventions):

> File names must be capitalized. For example: Myclass.php
>
> Class declarations must be capitalized. For example: class Myclass
>
> Class names and file names must match.

Answer (score 0):

To explain this, I assume you have a task to resize images.

**Step 1**: Copy the downloaded third party script to the third_party folder

**Step 2**: Create a folder called imageResize inside the third_party folder. So your final path would be application/third_party/imageResize/imageResize.php

**Step 3**: Call this library in the construct function in your controller.

```
include APPPATH . 'third_party/imageResize/imageResize.php';
```

In controller

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();      
    include APPPATH . 'third_party/imageResize/ImageResize.php';
}

public function image_resize() {

    $image = new \Eventviva\ImageResize($this->config->item('image_main').$fname);
    $image
        ->resizeToWidth(500,300)
        ->save($this->config->item('image_large').$fname)

        ->crop(100, 100)
        ->save($this->config->item('image_small').$fname)
    ;
}
```

Read more [here](https://www.tutsplanet.com/using-third-party-libraries-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Method alternative is locate on las line of Common.php on folder **system/core/** and loaded with Priority to apply on different needs.

locate: **system/core/Common.php** and inner this:

```
   /**
     * Function load traitphp
     *
     *
     * @link    http://hexome.cloud
     * @param   string  $directory  Function to check for
     * @return  void if the class exists and is safe to call,
     *          FALSE otherwise.
     */
if (! function_exists('load_traitphp')) {
    function load_traitphp($directory) {
      if(is_dir($directory)) {
          $scan = scandir($directory);
          unset($scan[0], $scan[1]); //unset . and ..
          foreach($scan as $file) {
             if(is_dir($directory."/".$file)) {
              load_traitphp($directory."/".$file);
             } else {
             if(strpos($file, '.php') !== false) {
                           if(strpos($directory, 'application') !== false) {
                        if(strpos($directory, 'libraries') !== false) {
                            if(strpos($file, 'trait') !== false || strpos($file, 'abstract') !== false || strpos($file, 'class') !== false) {
                                $message = '[ OK ] '. $directory."/".$file; log_message('debug', $message) ;
                                    require_once($directory."/".$file) ?? false;
                    } 
                }
              }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }
```

2 Create File -> application **/** libraries **/** 000-CommonAbstractx.**class**.php

```
<?php namespace application\libraries;
if (! class_exists("CommonAbstractx")) { 
abstract class CommonAbstractx implements \JsonSerializable
  {
      abstract public function jsonSerialize();
  }
}
```

3 Next inner on example Controller, Helper, Library or other whit need this:

```
 <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    load_traitphp(getcwd());
    //declare(strict_types=1);
    //use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
    use \application\libraries\CommonAbstractx;
```

**Warning**: alternative not compatibility with method here

```
$this->load->library('CommonAbstractx.calss.php');
// Disallow this option with this method
```